# How to merge table cells programmatically in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, typescript, merge, tinymce, cell

There is a command:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceTableMergeCells');
```

But it doesn't work. I think it requires that cells should be selected first and only then to call this command. 
So I found another command to do this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select(tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select('td'));
```

But it returns an error because `dom.select` works only with one element and if to add an array index and select only one `dom.select('td')[0]` it'll work, but it will select only one cell and I need to select all cells in a table to merge them. I can't find any sample in the docs or a solution to solve it.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the un-minified version of the table plugin to see how the core editor's code functions for this activity.  You can then replicate that wherever you need in your application.